# Number of values needed to distinguish two distributions

Tags: normal-distribution, confidence-interval

I have two normal distributions ($A$ and $B$). I know the standard deviation of both distributions ($σ_A$ and $σ_B$).

I want to find out how many data points ($n$) I will need to be able to distinguish the two distributions from one another, for a given expected value of $A$ and $B$.

For example, to give it some values: $μ_A = 0.300$, $σ_A = 0.013$, $μ_B = 0.280$, $σ_B = 0.014$.

How many points from A and B do I need for a 90, 95, 99% confidence interval to be able to distinguish the two?

Comment: How are you using confidence intervals to distinguish? What constitutes "different"?

Comment: As an example, let's say I generate two random populations with n values each and properties as described above: what n is required to be able to tell that the two populations have a different mean, and be able to determine the mean accurately.

Comment: You didn't respond to what I am asking. It sounds like you're computing a confidence interval for each of the two means. It is NOT clear how you then decide the means are different. What are you doing with those intervals? Once you have your two intervals, how do you conclude that the means are different (or fail to conclude they're different)? If you're doing something different from finding a CI for each of the means, can you clarify what you are doing?

Answer (score 1):

For normal distribution you are to use z-test. The number of observations needed depends on the desired power.

For Poisson distribution you may use an exact test. Again, the number of observations depends on the desired power of the test.

Comment: Doesn't the z-test only give me the option to compare one set of observations to a constant? That's not what I am looking for. I explained it a bit more in the comment above.

Comment: z-test can test whether you sample is from A distribution. The alternative B and the desired power define the required sample size.

Comment: You are to define what parameters are known and what are unknown. Are $\mu_A$ and/or $\mu_B$ known or unknown? Are $\sigma_A$ and/or $\sigma_B$ known/unknown?

Comment: μA, μB, σA, σB are all known and used to generate two populations of which then only the values are known.

Comment: If the distributions of the samples are known, then what is to be tested?

Comment: Let me word it differently. To the person doing the testing, they are not known. So, I generate two populations with μA, μB, σA, σB known to me. Now I give the two populations to you, and you can tell me if you have a high enough number (n) values to distinguish that the two populations have different means (μA =/= μB or better know that μA > μB). So wouldn't I want something like a two sample t-test? I'm not exactly sure how to set it up though.

Comment: Then you are to use Welch's t-test.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Welch's_t_test Again, the desired sample size depends on the parameters of the distributions and the needed power.

Comment: Ok, thanks, that does seem to the right test. However, what I'm really interested in is finding minimal n, for my null hypotheses to be true. I could  use Welch's test and a Monte Carlo model to simulate what n will work, but is there a way of doing that theoretically?

Comment: The minimal $n$ depends on the power needed, which in turn depends on the parameters of the distributions. If you need type I error probability 5% regardless of the power, then you may take 2 observations in each sample.

Comment: May be you want to use a sequential test? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequential_analysis

Comment: That's a good idea. I'll look into that as well.